# Java Virtual Joystick Output

Tags: java, controller, virtual, joystick

I'm working on a project which requires me to output joystick values such as the trigger buttons and d-pad with no actual joystick controller. Are there any libraries which allow me to easily create a virtual joystick to control through java?

Comment: Look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589380/virtual-joystick-in-java?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589380/virtual-joystick-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Oh, wow. Sorry. Didn't see that post. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I'm having extreme trouble with ppjoy. It just doesn't want to work with win7. Any chance there's any other libraries that don't depend on PPJoy?